# Project help, Involving tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter, project

I am trying to get tkinter to be able to find the total cost of some services that I input into the GUI. I haven't been able to get the actual calculations in the function "myClicker" to return any values to the screen. Looking for some help as to how I can get this code to take the inputs and use them for the calculations. I put in plenty of notes to try and help out too. This is my second post, go easy on me , Thanks!

```
import tkinter

service = {             #This is the dictionary that holds all of the services and their associated prices
    'Mergers and Acquisitions':3000,
    'Business Valuations':2000,
    'Financial Analysis & Operational Ideas':5000,
    'Strategic Planning Services':3500,
    'Specialized Strategic Consultion Services':4000,
    'Litigation Support':6000,
    '': 0
    }

services = [            #This is the list that holds all of the services (Used for the GUI output)
    '',
    'Mergers and Acquisitions',
    'Business Valuations',
    'Financial Analysis & Operational Ideas',
    'Strategic Planning Services',
    'Specialized Strategic Consultion Services',
    'Litigation Support'
    ]

window = tkinter.Tk()               #Creates the window (GUI)

class QuotaCalc:
    
    ## A class that asks for data about a client and then calculates
    ## both the time required for the service and the total estimate cost

    def __init__(self, main, cust_name = 'none', co_size = 0, option1=None, option2=None, option3=None):      ##This initializes the class with all of the variables that we will use

        self.co_name = tkinter.Label(main, text = 'Customer/Company Name', font=('Arial Narrow', 20)).grid(row=20, column=1)       #This displays text, the font is the font, and this tells the program what to display
        self.co_name_input = tkinter.Entry(main).grid(row=20, column=3)      #Allows user to input information       #by putting both on row 0, it aligns the text

#can add in blank labels to space out the boxes (reduce the font to something small) on the GUI

        clicked = tkinter.StringVar()           #initializing "clicked" as a string variable
        clicked2 = tkinter.StringVar()
        clicked3 = tkinter.StringVar()

        clicked.set(services[0])                #Text to be displayed on the menu dropdown
        clicked2.set(services[0])
        clicked3.set(services[0])

        timeRequired = 0                        #Initializing the variable timeRequired

        comp_size_input = tkinter.IntVar()      #Initializing the variable comp_size_input, to be called later in the myClicker function for the calculation

        self.co_size = tkinter.Label(main, text = 'Company Size', font=('Arial Narrow', 20)).grid(row=40, column=1)     #Company Size Label 
        self.comp_size_input = tkinter.Entry(main)                                                                      #Company Size Input Box
        self.comp_size_input.grid(row=40, column=3)                                                                     #Packing the Company Size Label

        self.option_1 = tkinter.Label(main, text = 'Service 1 Needed', font=('Arial Narrow', 20)).grid(row=60, column=1)    #Service Label
        drop = tkinter.StringVar()                                                                                          #Initalizing the variable drop (for the drop box input)
        self.drop = tkinter.OptionMenu( main , clicked , *service )                                                         #DropBox Entry Options
        self.drop.grid(row = 60, column = 3)                                                                                #packs the variable drop to the screen at the grid coordinates
        #dropped = tkinter.StringVar(drop)      Done in the myClicker function

        self.option_2 = tkinter.Label(main, text = 'Service 2 Needed', font=('Arial Narrow', 20)).grid(row=80, column=1)    #Service 2 Label
        drop2 = tkinter.StringVar()                                                                                         #Initalizing the variable drop2 (for the drop box input)
        self.drop2 = tkinter.OptionMenu( main , clicked2 , *service )                                                       #DropBox Entry Options
        self.drop2.grid(row = 80, column = 3)                                                                               #packs the variable drop2 to the screen at the grid coordinates
        #dropped2 = tkinter.StringVar(drop2)

        self.option_3 = tkinter.Label(main, text = 'Service 3 Needed', font=('Arial Narrow', 20)).grid(row=100, column=1)   #Service 3 Label
        drop3 = tkinter.StringVar()                                                                                         #Initalizing the variable drop3 (for the drop box input)
        self.drop3 = tkinter.OptionMenu( main , clicked3 , *service )                                                       #DropBox Entry Options    
        self.drop3.grid(row = 100, column = 3)                                                                              #packs the variable drop3 to the screen at the grid coordinates    
        #dropped3 = tkinter.StringVar(drop3)

        self.bt = tkinter.Button(main, text='Calculate', command = self.myClick, fg = "purple", bg = "light blue").grid(row=120, column=2)     #Creates the Calculate button to run the code that finds the total cost and time required    ##fg is foreground (color), bg is background (color)
        #Need to convert to when the button presses, it runs other functions of the class

        time_req = tkinter.Label(window, text = 'Time Required', font=('Arial Narrow', 20)).grid(row=140, column=1)                     #Creates the label Time Required to describe the output

        total_cost = tkinter.Label(window, text = 'Price Quote', font=('Arial Narrow', 20)).grid(row=160, column=1)                     #Creates the label Total Cost to describe the output

#To fix the calcuation problem, maybe make a boolean to see if the button has been clicked and set it to false, when the boolean becomes true run the functions that do the math?

    def myClick(self):                              #A function that activates once the button has been clicked and is desigend to calculate the total cost and time required for the services and output it to the GUI

        comp_size = self.comp_size_input.get()      #Initalizes the variable copm_size to be used in the time required calcuation
        comp_size = int(comp_size)                  #Converts the variable comp size into an int

        drop = str(self.drop)                       #Initializes and converts the chosen options for services 1, 2, and 3 into a string so they can be used to look up the prices in the service dictionary
        drop2 = str(self.drop2)
        drop3 = str(self.drop3)

        timeRequired = 0
        cost = 0

        if comp_size == 0:                          #This determines how much time will be necessary based on the size of the company
            self.timeRequired = 0                   #Need to add data validation for the company size
        elif comp_size <= 20:
            self.timeRequired = 1
        elif comp_size <= 40:
            self.timeRequired = 2
        elif comp_size <= 60:
            self.timeRequired = 3
        elif comp_size <= 80:
            self.timeRequired = 4
        elif comp_size <= 100:
            self.timeRequired = 5
        elif comp_size <= 150:
            self.timeRequired = 6
        else:
            self.timeRequired = 8

        cost = timeRequired * service[drop]                 #This section is used to determine the total costs based off of the services and the amount of time for the all the services
        if self.drop2 != '':
            cost += self.timeRequired * service[drop2]
        if self.drop3 != '':
            cost += self.timeRequired * service[drop3]

        myLabel = tkinter.Label(window,text = timeRequired)     #Designed to show the total time required and the total cost outputted on the GUI screen
        myLabel.grid(row=140, column=3)
        myLabel2 = tkinter.Label(window, text = cost)
        myLabel2.grid(row=160, column=3)

logo = tkinter.PhotoImage(file=r"C:\Users\brian\OneDrive\Documents\TCU\Junior Year\Second Semester\Business Information System Development INSC 30833\Bar Ad Pic.PNG")
##YOU MUST USE THE FILE PATH TO THE LOGO ON YOUR OWN COMPUTER
##THIS SHOWS MY PERSONAL FILE PATH

w1 = tkinter.Label(window, image=logo).grid(row=0, column = 2)          #Displays the picture at this grid coordinate


window.title('Barrington Advisory Quota Calculator')        #Window Title
window.geometry('1000x500')         #Sets the size of the window
#window.configure(bg='light blue') <- If we want to change the color of the background

e = QuotaCalc(window)

window.mainloop()       #Tells the program to continue running until the GUI is closed
```

Comment: You've posted far too much code. You need to create a new [mcve] specifically for this question with as little code as possible - just enough to reproduce the problem and no more.

Comment: Okay, thank and sorry about that.

Comment: btw a quick small suggestion would be to make the paths a bit more relative, so You could `import os` and then instead of using the full path to access the image You could try this: `os.path.join(os.getcwd(), 'file_name.extenstion')` (returns path as string) so that would make it access the file in the directory where the python file is, so all it would take is moving the file in the same directory where the python file is and it will be accessed

Comment: the issue is that You are not using the `StringVar()`s You assigned to each `OptionMenu`, so instead of: `drop = str(self.drop)` You should do `drop = self.clicked.get()` (no need for `str()` because it already is returned) obviously this requires to set all of those `StringVar()`s as `self.` attributes but otherwise it should work (as far as I tested)

Answer (score 0):

Note: The below code can be used by OP and anybody else with a little bit of tweaking.

Options like the ones in the comments (like [Matiiss](https://stackoverflow.com/users/14531062/matiiss)' comment on using `StringVar()`, which I am using here) may be more helpful to you, but I'd do it this way (there are many ways to do it, but I chose this one):

```py
    import tkinter
    from tkinter import ttk # This is to import *most* of the elements you need for a decent-ish GUI w/o calling "tkinter" then elemtent name. I do this because I am lazy

    # Setting up the GUI
    window = tkinter.Tk()
    window.title('Barrington Advisory Quota Calculator')                    # Window Title
    window.geometry('500x500')                                              # Sets the size of the window. Edit this to suit you. I am gonna put  500x500 because I am fine with it
    #window.configure(bg='light blue')                                      # If we want to change the color of the background (optional)
    window.resizable(False, False)                                          # Make sure that the current user cannot resize the window, keeping it at a fixed size

    # Some variables that are kinda important to OP's project (OP, uncomment the line below)
    # logo = tkinter.PhotoImage(file=r"C:\Users\brian\OneDrive\Documents\TCU\Junior Year\Second Semester\Business Information System Development INSC 30833\Bar Ad Pic.PNG")
    currentSelected = tkinter.StringVar()                                   # Kind of like doing 'currentSelected = ""' but with a bit of a special use later

    # Functions
    def fetch():
        localCurSel = currentSelected.get()                                 # Local variable to keep things easy imo

        # BIG DISCLAIMER:
        # I have no idea what is going on with the program OP is trying to make for a project
        # as I am very new to Python (~4 months)

        # Everything after the last line of this function can be expanded to OP's or anyone's
        # needs. So if you wanna do some fancy stuff with it, go ahead. What's next is how to display
        # the value from this function

        leaveMeEmpty.configure(text="Output: {0}".format(localCurSel))      # This is how you display the output of the function

    # I don't really get the "self" parameter much, so let's do this on how I'd write this
    # GUI Variables
    # NOTE: ALWAYS put functions ahead of GUI variables ESPECIALLY when calling a function with a variable
    intrLabl = ttk.Label(window, text="Barrington Advisory Quota Calculator")
    serviceList = ttk.Combobox(window, textvariable=currentSelected, width=50)
    serviceList["values"] = (            # This is the list that holds all of the services for the combobox
        '',
        'Mergers and Acquisitions',
        'Business Valuations',
        'Financial Analysis & Operational Ideas',
        'Strategic Planning Services',
        'Specialized Strategic Consultion Services',
        'Litigation Support'
    )
    serviceCalcul8 = ttk.Button(window, text="Calculate the ", command=fetch)

    leaveMeEmpty = ttk.Label(window, text="Output: ")                       # Variable kinda empty, eh? This is where I-can't-Explain-Further-than-This-because-I-am-a-noob-land begins

    # Combobox configs
    serviceList["state"] = "readonly"                                       # Make sure that the user cannot change what's inside the combobox except for the ones only in line 19

    # Placing the elements/GUI parts thingy
    intrLabl.pack()
    serviceList.pack(padx=10, pady=10)
    serviceCalcul8.pack(padx=10)
    leaveMeEmpty.pack(padx=10)

    window.mainloop()
```

I documented it/filled it with comments because it might help someone understand what's going on in a line, for example